# High Performance Coordinate System - Three.js

Tags: javascript, performance, three.js, coordinate-systems

**Conceptual Question**

I am building a flight simulator in Three.js. I intend to rip CSV data for Latitude, Longitude, and Elevation from Google Earth and transfer it into arcGIS to create a Digital Elevation Model (DEM). I then want to create the terrain based on the DEM. I already have a splat map texture shader I wrote and things are looking good.

However, I will need to add models and more specifically text and landing zones for the towns. This will require accurate XYZ coordinates.

I figure this is an interesting problem. I have seen one question before on stackoverflow similar to this but it was not quite to the same depth I'm looking for.

---

**1) How to create coordinate system that maps actual XYZ, Latitude, Longitude, Elevation data to a PlaneBufferGeometry?**

My assumption is that if I take a hypothetical 100,000 x 100,000 map sample then I will need to create a Plane that has matching vert count and then maps 1:1.

```
new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 100000, 100000, 100000, 100000 );
```

Then the trickier part of mapping lat long coordinates to this. Perhaps just a multiplier like * 100 or so per lat, long degrees?

---

**2) How to create the most efficient data structure for this. It will contain a lot of data.**

I am thinking the most efficient data structure would be an array with Z integers.

```
let vertArray = new Array(10000000000);

for (i = 0; i < 9999999999; i++) { 
  vertArray[i] = planeBufferGeometry.vertices[i].z;
}
```

Each 100,000 in the array would represent a Y coordinate, while each i value in said sections would be an X coordinate. The value of the Z coordinate would be stored in the array itself.

So hypothetically if I wanted to get X: 3, Y: 4, Z: ? it would be...

```
const xCoord = 3,
      yCoord = 4,
      index = (yCoord * 100000) + xCoord,
      zCoord = vertArray[index];
```

This is the smallest overhead approach I can think of... defining Array length ahead of time, keeping the array one dimensional, filling with only integers. Any better ideas? Perhaps creating an array would be unneeded and I could create an equation that pulls vert data directly from the rendered mesh?

---

**3) Are there ways to decrease the impact of large data stored in browser memory?**

I have yet to implement this but the idea of a 10 Million Length array in the browser is quite a lot in my mind. I would prefer being able to load the entire thing rather than doing some sort of AJAX call when the helicopter gets near the edge of a sub-plane. Think "zones" in MMORPG's.

Comment: You should use some kind of server, where all the height data will be stored and sent to browser in small parts (tiles). For example, Mapbox has great [elevation tiles](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/troubleshooting/access-elevation-data/) (or you can set up your own server). Moreover, you should use one `PlaneGeometry` for every tile and transform vertices height on GPU providing tiles as samplers2D to custom shader. New parts of terrain must appear as you move around the scene.

Comment: +1 for the mapbox reference... interesting link. I suppose the most robust properly engineered solution would be to do map tiles. The DEM I'm intending to create will allow for me to integrate ...say R (Red) value for vertices height into my existing shader. I'm using a class based approach for my simulator elements so creating new Terrain() instances shouldn't be difficult. I suppose a X, Y coordinate check on a timer to AJAX in the correct tile would be appropriate. Looks like I'm going to have to code up a Node backend.